# How this Assembly code contains carry?

Tags: assembly

```
include 'emu8086.inc'
ORG 100h
MOV AL, 255
ADD AL, 1
JC label1
PRINT 'no carry.'
JMP exit
label1:
PRINT 'has carry.'
exit:
RET
```

Comment: Because you're adding 1 to an 8-bit register (`AL`) that contains 255?

Comment: would u please explain the calculation...

Comment: `255` is `11111111` in binary. `11111111 + 1 = (1)00000000` where the `(1)` is a carry since `AL` is an 8-bit register and the result `100000000` is 9 bits. The `1` has to go somewhere. It goes into the carry `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Carry flag means, roughly: "the result of the last arithmetic operation is too large to fit into the target register". The target register is AL. It's a 8-bit register - it can only take values from 0 to 255. So the `ADD AL, 1` line generates a result of 256, which is indeed too large for AL. Thus, AL becomes 0 and the carry flag is set.